# Testing with emulator - Can't get response from bot when running from publish directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, publish

When i build and run the project everything works fine.

When i publish the project and run it from within publish directory, it doesn't respond to any message.

In the emulator i get the message:

Cannot post activity. Unauthorized.
POST403 directline.postActivity

```
dotnet myBot.dll    //from within publish directory, bot runs, doesnt repond to any message


dotnet run    //from project directory, everything works fine
```

Comment: How do you contact the bot in both cases?

Comment: I just test it with the bot emulator. Also, in publish case, when i open the connection with emulator i see in console output that the web api gets the message, it just behaves as the bot doesn't ever get instantiated. In both cases, app runs on same default Kestrel port, http 5000 and https 5001.

Comment: I edited the post with more detail. When i run the bot from publish directory i get the message : Cannot post activity. Unauthorized. POST403 directline.postActivity

Comment: So, the problem was that when you run in production environemnt you need to configure ngrok so that the bot service can communicate with your bot.

Comment: If that's the solution, add it as answer. That's perfectly fine. Maybe also add some info how you got to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was that i was tying to test production configuration trough localhost endpoint and in my .bot file i had this:

```
{
  "type": "endpoint",
  "appId": "myId",
  "appPassword": "myPass",
  "endpoint": "https://my.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
  "name": "production",
  "id": "4"
},
```

The production endpoint is the azure service. So, you either test locally on localhost or set your service on Azure to point to your localhost(ngrok provided link - In that case you need to configure ngrok to expose your localhost to the outside).

https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/